# String length getting reduced by using getline?

Tags: c++, getline

I am using getline and ignore but something is not working properly,
Below is the sample code which am not able to understand how it is working.

```
int main()
{
    string str;
    int t,length;
    cin>>t;  // t is the number of test cases

    while(t--!=0)
    {
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin,str);
        length=str.size();

        cout<<"length="<<length;
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
2
hey hi
length 6
hey hi 
length 5
```

Why is the length decreasing? Is this because of getline and ignore function? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Run 3+ test cases of the same string. I think only one will differ.

Comment: only the first output is greater by 1 compared to all other outputs.

Comment: Try moving `cin.ignore()` (which you are using incorrectly by the way) outside of the loop, after the `cin>>t` call. This will fix your issue, but please, FOR THE LOVE OF GOD, read documentation and figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

`cin.ignore()` defaults to ignoring one character.

If you output your string each time, you'll see that in later cases the string is equal to "ey hi". The h is being dropped.

The value of the string held by `cin` drops its first character before being passed to getline.

Since you're using getline, you can simply remove the `cin.ignore()` from your loop and your program should work as intended.

However, you should also change your `cin>>t;` line. In this case, the `ignore()` is dropping the line return after the input value `2`. A `stringstream` here allows for a `getline(...)` function, or alternatively you can use `cin.ignore(str.max_size(), '\n');`.

In the case of the `stringstream`, your code would become:

```
#include <sstream>  // stringstream
#include <string>   // std::string
#include <iostream> // cin

int main()
{
    string str;
    int t,length;
    getline(cin, str);
    std::stringstream stream;
    stream << str;
    if (!(stream >> t)) {
        // Couldn't process to int
    }
    // cin>>t;  // t is the number of test cases
    // No longer need this line.

    while(t--!=0)
    {
        // cin.ignore(); Drop this too
        getline(cin,str);
        length=str.size();

        cout<<"length="<<length;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not each time, i tried for the same string but only for the first time it shows actual length after that for every case it shows length decreased by 1, but why only once?

Comment: In the first case your '2' is being ignored

Comment: if you remove cin.ignore() what happens is it skips the getline() and directly prints length.

Comment: 2 shows number of iterations so i didn't get what you mean by '2' is ignored.

Comment: In the first case `ignore()` skips the line break (`\n`)

Comment: @anton savin: but why size decreases only in first case?

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is giving a different length is becaus your `ignore()` function ignores only one character. The first time round it ignores the `return` key you pressed after entering the number. But `std::getline()` deletes the `return` character for you. So the second time round `ignore()` deletes the first letter of your string making it `"eh hi"`.

```
int main()
{
    string str;
    int t, length;

    cin >> t;  // does not remove the RETURN character

    while(t-- != 0)
    {
        // first removed RETURN character after removes first letter
        cin.ignore(); 

        getline(cin, str);
        length = str.size();

        cout << "length = " << length;
    }
}
```

**Try using this instead:**

```
int main()
{
    string str;
    int t, length;

    cin >> t;  // does not remove the RETURN character

    while(t-- != 0)
    {
//        cin.ignore(); // dont do this here please

        // cin >> ws skips all whitespace characters
        // including the return character
        getline(cin >> ws, str); 
        length = str.size();

        cout << " length = " << length;
    }
}
```

**Alternatively** (maybe better) you can move the `ignore()` function out of the loop to where t is really needed:

```
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    string str;
    int t, length;

    cin >> t;  // does not remove the RETURN character

    // ignore as many characters as necessary including the return
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    while(t-- != 0)
    {
        // cin.ignore(); // not here

        getline(cin, str);
        length = str.size();

        cout << " length = " << length;
    }
}
```

The `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` looks complicated but it is the only way to guarantee that any spurious characters (like spaces) are removed. You can probably get away with just `cin.ignore()` for the exercise if you want.

Read up on [std::istream::ignore()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/)

Comment: I understood but for the second and further cases cin.ignore() line is executed before taking the input from getline and then i print it so how is this cin.ignore() working for this input?

Comment: @CodeHacker I don't use `cin.ignore()` in the second case. Inside the `getline()` I added `cin >> ws` which reads any spaces and RETURN characters *before* getting the line. So it basically makes sure your input lines begin with a letter. If you want to be able to get lines beginning with spaces you need the third example.

Comment: @CodeHacker The third example's `ignore()` function basically reads as many characters as a stream can contain (that's the `max()` part) until if finds a RETURN, which it extracts.

Comment: I got it, but in case just in case if i use cin.ignore() inside as i did it in my code why first char gets ignored after taking input as cin.ignore() is executed before taking input.

Comment: @CodeHacker Inside the loop `ignore()` deletes the first letter of the string you type. It doesn't do that the first time round because the RETURN character is left over from when you input the number (outside the loop), so it ignores that instead of the first letter of the first string.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not interested in whitespace,
then use `getline(cin >> ws, str)`